# rake db:create - collation issues

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, osx-snow-leopard, collation

```
kratos-iii:railsproj zachinglis$ rake db:create
(in /Users/zachinglis/Sites/rails/railsproj)
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"mysql", "host"=>"localhost", "username"=>"root", "password"=>nil, "database"=>"railsproj_development"}, charset: utf8, collation: utf8_general_ci (if you set the charset manually, make sure you have a matching collation)
```

I had no issues using Sequel Pro and even creating said database.

How do I resolve this?
Having an empty password never gave me issues before. And I really doubt thats it.

Comment: What exactly do want to know? Please write a real question!

Comment: Your password being empty probably is the problem, but who knows with such a vague "question"?  I would recommend restarting the question with a question mark somewhere so people know what the actual point in question is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was having the same problem than you, me and my friends were all going mad because of it, until we've found this link http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2009/8/30/upgrading-to-snow-leopard

I've just followed the mysql installation steps and it worked great here :]

Answer (score 3):

I happened on same problem after installing new database server MySQL5.0 to 5.1.
If you have installed new db-server, Your mysql gem library is not suitable for your database server.
You may solve this by reinstall mysql gem lib.

```
 sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386" gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/your/mysql_config
```

Answer (score 3):

Re-install mysql-server and mysql-client using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```

and then some libraries you need to install to make MySQL available to ruby:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby
```

This all solved my problem. Try it !!! :)

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this as well on a fresh Snow Leopard install.

I had another project that created the databases without issue, but my primary project would give the errors you described. After poking around, the only difference was the former specified a socket, whereas the failing project (and yours too) uses a host.

That is to say, this database.yml causes the problem:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  database: fanvsfan_development
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost
```

But this works:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  database: fanvsfan_development
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

I'm unsure what the actual difference is, but this seems like a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Using RVM? Do this for Rails v 2.3

```
export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" ; gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri mysql -v 2.7 -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good reference. And I got if fixed through this 
http://www.ultrasaurus.com/sarahblog/2008/12/getting-started-with-rails-2-day-1/

Answer (score -1):

Does the database already exist?  Is MySQL setup and running?  What changed? (OS Upgrade maybe)?  Does a fresh rails app work?  What about your other environments (test, production)?

Is there a back trace? you could post (use rake --trace db:create). Usually MySQL is returns a very explicit error message, rake is just eating it.

Comment: The database exists, I can access MySQL. I created the db as a test & created a table.

I started FRESH on Snow Leopard. All environments fail similarly.

Backtrace:
** Invoke db:create (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke rails_env (first_time)
** Execute rails_env
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:create
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"mysql", "host"=>"localhost", "username"=>"root", "password"=>nil, "database"=>"railsproj_development"}, charset: utf8, collation: utf8_general_ci (if you set the charset manually, make sure you have a matching collation)