# Error when trying to create database with Rails, rake db:create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Ruby1.9 and Rails 2.3.4 and I have mysql-ruby (2.8.1) gem installed.

when I try rake db:create I get the following

> Couldn't create database for
>   {"adapter"=>"mysql",
>   "database"=>"war_development",
>   "username"=>"root", "password"=>nil,
>   "host"=>"localhost"}, charset: utf8,
>   collation: utf8_unicode_ci (if you set
>   the charset manually, make sure you
>   have a matching collation)

My database.yml has the following for development

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  database: war_development
  username: root
  password: 
  host: localhost
```

Any ideas what's going wrong?

Thanks,

Tam

Comment: From the error I would say that the charset of your database does not match what you are trying to do:

    charset: utf8
    collation: utf8_unicode_ci

Not sure if there is a way to set the charset of a query in rails?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you allowed to use the root user without password?  Is the mysqlserver listening on 127.0.0.1 or localhost?

Comment: I used 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost...it seems to make difference.

Comment: maybe this makes it more clear: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382602/difference-between-127-0-0-1-and-localhost

Comment: Wow, for me it was the opposite: 127.0.0.1 didn't work but localhost did

Answer (score 4):

Strange to see some behaviour changed, and I don't know if it is specific to snow leopard. I use tiger and got the same error. I added

```
  host: 127.0.0.1
```

to the following (ofcourse with a correct mysql root/pw)

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: blog_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: *********
  socket: /tmp/mysqld.sock
```

And it worked (on tiger/gem mysql-2.8.1/mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.30). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the steps in another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363772/rake-dbcreate-collation-issues). However, the command for my installation is different from that of there, as I am not upgrading an existing db but installing a fresh one. So instead of advised one

```
$ sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

I typed the following

```
$ sudo gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql
```

PS: host: localhost remains as is, no need to change to 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sudo gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql
```

works for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You will check out your usrname and password whether its correct or not. 
Also you will check out whether your mysql server is working correctly.
and also some time found the problem of socket path most of the time its is inside /tmp directory but sometimes it may not be. so try with with the default path.

Hopefully if you will try this it will work for you.