# What does collation mean in this particular error and what is the charset?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to make a rails 3.1 app using mysql, its my first time using it 
I am getting an error when I try to `rake db:create`

**The Error**

Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.socket' (2) Couldnt create database for {*database.yml info in here*}
(if you set the charset manually, make sure you have a matching collation)

I was looking at this link http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2009/8/30/upgrading-to-snow-leopard/ which was posted in this question here [rake db:create - collation issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363772/rake-dbcreate-collation-issues)

but I dont think that applies, doesnt mysql get installed when i do install gem mysql 'gem-version'?
can someone please help me solve this error? I am also running osx 10.7

Thank you very much in advance!

**This is what my gem file looks like**

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem "mysql2"
gem "activerecord-mysql2-adapter"

gem 'pry'
gem 'pry-debugger'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
    group :development, :test do
        gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.0'
        gem 'database_cleaner'
        gem 'shoulda-matchers'
    end

    gem 'jquery-rails'
```

**my database.yml**

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: Training_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: Training_test
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: Training_production
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost
```

Comment: Your config/database.yml should have :
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: <yourapp>_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

And use mysql2 gem.

Comment: Hey thank you for your response, I updated the gem file, but the database.yml file doesnt have "socket:" do i just add this under password?

Comment: after adding "socket:" i still get the same error, I appreciate your response thank you very much but can you be a little more specific?

Comment: Try creating the db manually. From terminal: "mysql -uroot" This will take you inside mysql. Then do "create database Training_development;" . I also see host specified, instead of " socket: /tmp/mysql.sock" in your .yml.