# rake db:migrate gives error mysql 2 gem

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I am trying to do `rake db:create` in one of my rails app. I get the error that says

```
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"mysql2", "encoding"=>"utf8", "reconnect"=>false, "database"=>"new-db", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"root", "password"=>"password"}, {:charset=>"utf8", :collation=>"utf8_unicode_ci"}
(If you set the charset manually, make sure you have a matching collation)
```

This is what my `database.yml` looks like

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: new-db
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: password
```

I tried adding `host:localhost` in above code, It didn't work.

Also, when I am trying to login to mysql with `mysql -u root -password`, I am getting

```
 ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Can someone please help here..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rake db:create - collation issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363772/rake-dbcreate-collation-issues)

Comment: @Ilya It didn't help me...

Comment: which os are you using?

Comment: ubuntu 14.04 is the operating system

Comment: Your `mysql.sock` file is corrupted. I guess this will do the trick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363772/rake-dbcreate-collation-issues#3757874

Comment: @Emu error is regarding character-set not regarding socket

Comment: I get different set of errors after this, I tried that ..

`dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

`

Comment: remove `encoding` from yml

Comment: @uzaif, read the question first. He cannot access mysql manually because of the socket, how do you think the project can access that?

Comment: I get same above error by removing `encoding`

Comment: hate it the way people mark things duplicate even when I am saying that didn't answer the question.

Comment: @Suraj i think your mysql is not running

Comment: @VishalJAIN  `sudo service mysql status` 

This is what I get

`mysql start/post-start, process 20721
 post-start process 20722
`

Comment: Please run `sudo install mysql-server-5.5` and show us the output.

Comment: [here's](http://pastebin.com/XUwX2eB9) the output

Comment: Have you installed mysql-server ? if not  - `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`

Comment: Obviously I have installed `mysql-server` @Amit

Comment: @Suraj try to reboot a machine. It looks like you have two `apt` processes running.

Comment: please have look to this one [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990708/error-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysq]

Comment: @mudasobwa rebooted. trying again

Comment: `E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
`

Got this. the whole distro is upset it seems :-s

Comment: `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/lock`

Comment: `gradle-2.10 mariadb-common
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
E: Could not get lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/cache/apt/archives/
`

After doing the above command

Comment: `sudo rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives/lock` and retry with `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: [this](http://pastebin.com/7XT6Vkq5) error now

Comment: Just `sudo rm -rf WHATEVER_FILE_IS_REPORTED_AS_LOCKED`. This should [hopefully] help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112047/discussion-between-suraj-and-mudasobwa).

Answer (score -1):

add tab space before each line except first line EX. below

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: new-db
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: password
```

Comment: It is like that only in my yml file.